# How to correctly escape command arguments from an environment variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I'm trying to merge the output of 2 `find` commands and pipe it to the next operator. The arguments passed to both `find` executions are very similar so I'd like to keep it DRY

```bsh
FIND_CMD_ARGS="-type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) -print0"
CMD_OUTPUT=`{ find $PROJECT_PATH -not -path '*/Pods/*' $FIND_CMD_ARGS; find . -path '*/Pods/MyProject*/*' $FIND_CMD_ARGS }`
```

For some reason this doesn't work and this is the output I get

```
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
find: -type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) -print0: unknown primary or operator
```

I *think* the issue is related to how the `args` in the `FIND_CMD_ARGS` environment variable are escaped but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a variable to store more than one argument, use an array:

```
find_args=(-type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) -print)
cmd_output=$(
  find "$PROJECT_PATH" ! -path '*/Pods/*' "${find_args[@]}"
  find . -path '*/Pods/MyProject*/*' "${find_args[@]}"
)
```

I also

- added the missing quotes around your variable expansions
- changed the variable name to lower case as it doesn't look like it should be an environment variable (and anyway, now that it's an array, it can't be exported to the environment).
- changed the non-standard `-not` to standard `!` (`-iname` is another non-standard predicate).
- use the `$(...)` form of command substitution instead of the old deprecated `` `...` `` one.
- changed `-print0` to `-print` as `bash` variables can't store NUL bytes.

Another approach could have been to declare a function:

```
myfind() {
  find "$@" -type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) -print
}
cmd_output=$(
  myfind "$PROJECT_PATH" ! -path '*/Pods/*'
  myfind . -path '*/Pods/MyProject*/*'
)
```

Now, there's little you can do with that `$cmd_output` variable, as you can't reliably get the list of files back with `-print` instead of `-print0`.

With bash 4.4 or newer, you can use an array instead and use:

```
myfind() {
  find "$@" -type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) -print0
}
readarray -td '' files < <(
  myfind "$PROJECT_PATH" ! -path '*/Pods/*'
  myfind . -path '*/Pods/MyProject*/*'
)
```

Comment: Amazing bash-fu! Thanks so much!