# Pass qouted filename with spaces in a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, escape-characters, whitespace

In a bash shell, consider this:

```
$ x="-name 'foo bar'"
$ find $x
find: paths must precede expression: `bar''
$ find -name 'foo bar'
./foo bar
```

What can I put in `$x` to make `find $x` behave like `find -name 'foo bar'`?

Comment: See [How to correctly escape command arguments from an environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516170/how-to-correctly-escape-command-arguments-from-an-environment-variable) and [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Thanks, looks that I haven't googled it right.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put things that are separate (`-name` and `foo bar`) into a single string.

Instead, use an array:

```bsh
args=( -name 'foo bar' )

find . "${args[@]}"
```

The quotes around the expansion of the array variable ensures that each  element is individually quoted.  This ensures that `foo bar` is a single argument.

You may also use the positional parameters:

```bsh
set -- -name 'foo bar'

find . "$@"
```

Again, the quoting of `"$@"` are essential.

When you put `-name 'foo bar'` in your variable and use it unquoted with `find`, the shell will split the value on spaces, tabs and newlines.  This means that tho `find` utility gets the arguments `-name`, `'foo`, and `bar'`.  Since the `bar'` argument is unknown to `find`, it complains.

If you had globbing patterns in your string, as in `-name '*.txt'`, then the shell would split that into `-name` and `'*.txt'`, and would then use `'*.txt'` as a globbing pattern to expand names in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Linux supports that find syntax, but it's not universal. It does not work on most BSD derivatives, for example, yielding the following:

```
bash-3.2$ find -name 'foo bar'
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

Your problem isn't location, it's quoting and quote interpretation.
Could you replace your code with

```
x='foo bar'
find -name "$x"
```

Alternatively, you could potentially try using eval:

```
x="-name 'foo bar'"
eval "find $x"
```

Which at least on my system resulted in:

```
bash-5.1$ x="-name 'foo bar'"
bash-5.1$ eval "find $x"
./foo bar
```

Which I believe is the desired result.